# OCSP Stapling error with Apache (self certificate)

Tags: apache, openssl, ocsp

I have errors with my local OCSP and local certification authority when doing some OCSP stapling in Apache. My website is accessible by https without any issues (I have added the root to authorities) whatsoever but apache is returning an error :

```
[Fri Nov 25 19:03:09.049310 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 1001] AH01935: stapling_check_response: certificate ID not present in response!
[Fri Nov 25 19:03:09.049429 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 1001] AH01943: stapling_renew_response: error in retrieved response!
```

Here is the openssl s_client attempt :

```
OCSP response:
======================================
OCSP Response Data:
    OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
    Response Type: Basic OCSP Response
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Responder Id: C17DC2EDAF9ABBD01FF2DC7FB5C7C2C4593047AF
    Produced At: Nov 25 18:03:09 2022 GMT
    Responses:
    Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha256
      Issuer Name Hash: 5FE12EE96C3771B8F6FA83E828A2F69067078B850E3A19B608371119E9C6AFA1
      Issuer Key Hash: 1183E9B1BB88058B7A99ADD680EFB295805E61B62D9C98137B2E8B98665AD53A
      Serial Number: 221D839F050959811CE852B66C532FDE69B581DB
    Cert Status: good
    This Update: Nov 25 18:03:09 2022 GMT
    Next Update: Nov 26 10:03:09 2022 GMT

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        9e:2c:7a:55:4a:f0:ab:dc:d2:93:96:45:01:97:cf:7b:d3:81:
        33:8e:0f:b9:06:d3:8c:18:c5:3b:5a:e7:a4:f2:3d:5d:2e:12:
        5c:10:17:ef:5c:03:d8:20:20:99:16:02:be:8c:48:97:73:57:
        16:fb:81:56:43:4f:6f:48:33:60:8b:92:e0:2f:21:de:54:84:
        0e:cf:8f:f0:67:51:39:b6:8f:47:6a:2f:6b:b9:d8:b8:fa:c4:
        3f:c6:6d:37:1d:48:11:19:07:84:15:d9:63:bb:5e:cb:53:ba:
        1f:85:44:3f:82:dc:2a:68:7d:e9:60:70:3f:3a:5e:b2:18:fe:
        d2:dc:07:22:e9:b0:0f:f2:f4:d9:69:53:98:21:3a:35:67:6f:
        45:f5:b1:39:1a:d7:19:48:c2:b3:ce:cd:97:0e:de:19:18:58:
        38:31:78:0f:a5:10:14:07:ac:c1:d1:0e:a7:c9:76:80:c6:58:
        eb:85:ee:fa:0f:4c:ec:6c:30:ec:69:5c:34:8e:88:1d:dc:c7:
        c6:a8:92:83:21:5e:d6:ee:de:9b:87:ac:6a:28:bc:b6:31:18:
        cf:00:6f:0f:8e:ba:a1:30:3b:24:64:fc:1a:98:aa:72:c9:76:
        f9:6e:10:18:86:09:79:58:6e:d7:4f:70:b8:db:33:a1:df:3d:
        d7:45:25:39
======================================
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = sslvpn.local, C = FR, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, OU = IT
   i:CN = SSL VPN Services, C = FR, O = SSL VPN
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Nov 17 19:52:50 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Nov 17 19:52:50 2023 GMT
 1 s:CN = SSL VPN Services, C = FR, O = SSL VPN
   i:CN = SSL VPN Root, C = FR, O = SSL VPN Inc.
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Nov 16 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 23:59:59 2029 GMT
 2 s:CN = SSL VPN Root, C = FR, O = SSL VPN Inc.
   i:CN = SSL VPN Root, C = FR, O = SSL VPN Inc.
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Nov 16 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 23:59:59 2049 GMT
---
```

The certificate is as follows :

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            22:1d:83:9f:05:09:59:81:1c:e8:52:b6:6c:53:2f:de:69:b5:81:db
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = SSL VPN Services, C = FR, O = SSL VPN
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 17 19:52:50 2022 GMT
            Not After : Nov 17 19:52:50 2023 GMT
        Subject: CN = sslvpn.local, C = FR, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, OU = IT
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b0:ec:15:24:d8:06:68:1a:f8:09:ae:90:3e:2a:
                    9b:e2:7d:35:ec:cd:c5:cf:5b:7d:e3:ac:76:35:08:
                    37:01:a2:56:14:e3:34:7d:69:38:c0:e6:6e:e7:ae:
                    72:bd:03:f7:68:6e:ae:e6:72:c2:bf:0d:88:ad:95:
                    de:97:50:51:15:50:de:08:99:e7:ea:10:a3:df:89:
                    f5:d4:34:81:3d:79:67:ae:39:69:4a:b7:f7:34:3a:
                    cc:f3:a4:05:84:fc:b9:61:94:8a:50:bf:09:70:8a:
                    99:c0:44:5f:b8:65:d5:f9:a6:69:00:94:39:b9:bc:
                    08:aa:a5:23:6f:31:6b:86:14:81:45:53:23:a4:78:
                    ec:23:c9:45:e8:95:55:7a:44:11:95:73:fc:45:27:
                    e5:49:0c:ff:c6:10:24:4b:1c:6a:b0:0d:82:3c:01:
                    da:98:de:82:ac:4b:2d:ee:6d:17:c1:ef:9b:cd:25:
                    b9:b7:71:50:92:e7:9e:aa:28:55:47:f7:a7:6f:ea:
                    b6:d3:37:96:89:af:f4:f2:18:f3:32:a5:88:be:12:
                    d1:24:08:99:40:e2:ac:31:49:d5:52:c5:3e:a9:38:
                    4e:21:d9:28:4b:ed:90:86:62:53:f3:04:d0:5c:f8:
                    37:82:9c:2e:d9:7c:02:a8:1b:b3:96:3e:27:c5:e7:
                    40:35
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                9B:FE:4D:F9:81:90:DF:52:AB:0A:53:66:45:AA:99:06:29:95:82:7F
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                C1:7D:C2:ED:AF:9A:BB:D0:1F:F2:DC:7F:B5:C7:C2:C4:59:30:47:AF
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:sslvpn.local, DNS:*sslvpn.local, email:*******
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:*******
            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: Policy Qualifier CPS
                  CPS: *******
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        64:32:ed:c5:ca:6a:e8:2d:58:b7:7c:0e:0f:6b:f5:51:38:df:
        42:2c:c6:13:60:26:f6:ae:13:23:be:83:95:d7:ad:88:7c:38:
        dc:9f:01:61:e2:f3:5d:cf:16:b6:6e:9c:3e:76:07:ee:68:67:
        17:d7:83:d2:38:b3:df:3a:cd:bb:f6:34:fd:1b:85:11:bb:a4:
        06:97:a5:c0:60:81:f9:a1:40:67:70:e9:cb:d3:76:43:1c:10:
        b2:1a:7c:1a:5f:3d:48:5a:ee:88:8b:fc:62:fb:c9:f3:33:ef:
        bb:84:f3:14:aa:9d:4c:ac:52:d0:da:c8:48:1d:c8:8b:bb:34:
        cf:b9:41:28:95:21:ae:76:b2:42:5b:ed:89:fa:6c:3a:a2:8a:
        66:ad:af:2d:ae:f3:fa:6d:fb:2f:2d:56:75:d4:9e:b3:88:90:
        c2:4c:c2:cf:f5:b8:2d:75:45:22:6d:ed:6c:46:36:ad:a7:fa:
        dd:13:e5:b0:f0:c2:24:13:8b:08:ef:65:4b:82:08:62:a6:9b:
        06:e5:63:25:f0:2e:fc:87:9c:f7:8e:5a:42:6a:a6:99:90:c9:
        3d:06:be:c1:15:1d:92:b0:38:d7:0d:fe:68:43:41:f6:63:5c:
        62:9e:9a:0a:0f:68:f1:4a:bb:d4:3a:b2:50:2e:d1:5c:1c:54:
        51:46:df:70
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Why apache returns this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many researches, I have understand the issue.

During a request, Apache and browsers use SHA-1 hash to computer issuer key hash and issuer key name like this :

```
OCSP Request Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Requestor List:
        Certificate ID:
          Hash Algorithm: sha1
          Issuer Name Hash: 467F6C7AF3946017DA85E1ACE9BA717A2CCEF939
          Issuer Key Hash: C17DC2EDAF9ABBD01FF2DC7FB5C7C2C4593047AF
          Serial Number: 094E315FA6ADB9BC3EA20564A7B22EE6EBAA55E0
```

This is due to [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280.html#section-4.2.1.1). However my OCSP was hashing using SHA-256 so the issuer name hash and key hash was different. It was not a big issue for Firefox as it was not checking this but Apache stapling is checking issuer key hash and therefore was returning an error.
My return :

```
Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha256
```

Therefore you should extract the algorithm from OCSP request to computer hashes for the OCSP response. However, it is recommended to use SHA256 to compute the private key signature hash because SHA1 is not considered secure.

Changing the hash algorithm deletes Apache error and stapling is working fine.